# Magento 2 - Extend layout of another module

Tags: magento2, module, layout

I have developed a module vendor_module1 and I want to extend the layout of magento_customer module. Is there a way to do it in module? or only in theme? Is it a good practice to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can extend a module's layout by creating the same layout file in your custom module.

In case you want to extend, for example, "*customer_account_create.xml*" layout then in your extension you need to create file:

*/app/code/Vendor/Module1/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml*